# Get last month and current month record of user in codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

We want to get the records of last month of user point.
We have User Created date Ex. **25-08-2015**.
Second table is user points.

> But Main Thing is : -
>
> if current date is **23-11-2015**

we want record between in point table: -

last month: **25-09-2015 to 25-10-2015**

Current Month : **25-10-2015 to 25-11-2015**

> if current date is **28-11-2015**

we want redcord between in point table:-

last month: **25-10-2015 to 25-11-2015**

Current Month : **25-11-2015 to 25-12-2015**

> **Note:** Means User Created date is starting user month and end of user month

Comment: no matter what the date is, you want to fetch from 25th to 25th??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following:

```
function get_day_for_date($date)
{
     $day = date('d', strtotime($date));
     return $day;
}

$user_reg = "25-08-2015";

$current_month_start = get_day_for_date($user_reg) ."-". date("m-Y",    strtotime("-1 months"));
$current_month_end = get_day_for_date($user_reg) ."-". date("m-Y");

$last_month_start = get_day_for_date($user_reg) ."-". date("m-Y",  strtotime("-2 months"));
$last_month_end = get_day_for_date($user_reg) ."-". date("m-Y", strtotime("-1 month"));

//echo $current_month_start . ", ". $current_month_end;
//echo "<br>";
//echo $last_month_start . ", ". $last_month_end;
```